# Best way to just add an item to a zsh prompt

Tags: virtualenv, zsh, prompt

I have been working on a way to add an item to my zsh prompt to allow it to show the active virtualenv.  I followed [this blog post](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2013/003/), and got this so far:

```
function virtual_env_prompt () {
  REPLY=${VIRTUAL_ENV+(${VIRTUAL_ENV:t}) }
}
grml_theme_add_token virtual-env -f virtual_env_prompt '%F{magenta}' '%f'
zstyle ':prompt:grml-large:left:setup' items \
    rc virtual-env jobs history shell-level change-root time \
    date newline user at host path vcs percent
```

It works, but the problem is I have to take the items from the prompt and repeat them in my config file.  Is there any way I can just add the virtualenv item to the prompt without repeating everything else as well?

Comment: If you just want to prepend or append to the prompt you can always use `+`. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll need to write your own prompt function (or use some ugly hack like doing an in-place replacement which is more trouble than its worth).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using `+`.  Do you mean to append it to the beginning of the actual prompt variable?

Comment: If you want to append to existing prompt, do `PROMPT+='$(whatever)'`. If you want to prepend to prompt, do `PROMPT='$(whatever)'+PROMPT`. Note that I'm using single quotes, and you would need to set the option `PROMPT_SUBST` to make it work (but it's the preferred way).

Answer (score 0):

To append to an existing prompt (`PS1`), you can use the *plus-equal* operator: `PS1+='TXT'`.
You must enable [Prompt Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) and use single quotes.

Example:

```bash
# Expand variables and commands in PROMPT variables
setopt PROMPT_SUBST

_current_user() {
    echo -n $USER
}

PS1+='$(_current_user) '
```